# image of symmetric matrices under representation of $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, representation-theory

Let $W$ be a real vector space of dimension $2$ and let $\rho_k:GL_2(\mathbb{R}) \to GL(\mathbf{S}^kW)$ be the standard representation of $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$. Since $\rho_k$ is polynomial, it naturally extends to a map $\tilde \rho_k:Mat_2(\mathbb{R}) \to End(\mathbf{S}^kW)$. 
Denote $Sym_2(\mathbb{R})$ the space of real symmetric $2 \times 2$ matrices. Do we know the dimension of the vector space in $End(\mathbf{S}^kW)$ generated by 
$\tilde \rho_k(Sym_2(\mathbb{R}))$?

Comment: Perhaps I'm dense but $\rho_k$ is faithful and therefore so is $\tilde\rho_k$. So the dimension must be three, right?

Comment: @Marek: There is no reason for the map $\rho_k$ to respect addition of matrices --- only products.

Comment: I think it is (k+1)*(k+2)/2.  In a fairly standard basis, you get that the strictly upper triangular part is component-wise a multiple of the strictly lower triangular part (different coefficients per component).  At least this works for k ≤ 5.

Comment: @Jyrki: I missed the word *generated*. So the question is indeed non-trivial. Thanks.

Comment: @Jack: I agree that it should be (k+1)*(k+2)/2. But I do not see why saying that the upper triangular part is component-wise a multiple of the strictly lower triangular part implies that I get (k+1)*(k+2)/2 linearly independent matrices.

Comment: For the linearly independent side, I just constructed the matrices.  I checked it (spanning and independent) up to k ≤ 20.  I didn't check if the independent set was easy to specify, but I think the linear dependencies are easy to figure out.

Comment: @JackSchmidt Please consider converting your comments into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).